# signature problems on java class

Tags: xpages

VERY OFTEN I get the followeing error after building a project in DDE:

> HTTP JVM: java.lang.SecurityException: Error verifying signature for
>   resource WEB-INF/classes/se/sebank/namis/utils/Utils$Params.class. For
>   more detailed information, please consult error-log-0.xml located in
>   E:/IBM/
>
> HTTP JVM: com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet$ExtendedServletException:
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: se.sebank.namis.utils.Utils$Params

All other classes do not give problems, but mostly this file causes problems.

Is there anything I can do to improve the build process.

My "approach" is currently trying cleaning, building the project several times. Sometimes I have to close and restart DDE

Comment: this is the content of the class: https://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=pure-java-version-of-dblookup-dbcolumn-with-cache-sort-and-unique

Comment: Try signing the db to make sure that all design elements are correctly signed

Comment: I am the only designer in the project. Every design element is already signed by me.

Comment: What does *error-log-0.xml* say?

Comment: Remove and reimport that code. Probably the notes note behind that design element got corrupted.

Comment: That 'Params' innerclass gave me problems years ago. Move it to its own package (Java element) should do the job.